# Calculating elevation profile of a trail?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

What would be the best way to calculate an elevation profile of a trail remotely (without using altimeter/gps tracking your steps)? For example, to do it in the most rudimentary way you might take a topo map and measure distances and elevation changes along the course of a trail. Can you do this with USGS topo maps or do you need a DEM? What would be the best data source? I don't have access to Arc, just QGIS.

Comment: I have done a very crude rudimentary trail profile using Google Earth.  You can either trace the trail line manually or bring in the layer as a KML file - then there are profile tools within it to give you an elevation profile.

Comment: Did you try the [Profiletool plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/)? For DEM data you can e.g. get data from [SRTM](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an excellent QGIS plugin called [Profile Tool](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/profiletool/wiki) that creates trail profiles.  In the first screenshot, I overlaid an OpenLayers Google satellite image over a DEM and hand digitized my path using the profile tool.  The second screenshot shows the profile results.

You can download DEM's across the USA from the [National Map](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/), [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) or the [NRCS Geospatial Data Gateway](http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/GDGOrder.aspx)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks. Has anyone used D3.js for visualizing elevation profiles? Maybe it's overkill but I was just thinking there might be some cool stuff you could do with that. I don't have js skills but working on html/css.

Comment: Looks like that combination is used here: http://cycleroute.org/

Answer (score 4):

If it were me (meaning this is my opinion and there are lots of ways to solve this problem), I would:

1. Digitize the trail as a series of points, placing one point every X meters depending on the resolution you are looking for.
2. Using a DEM pull the elevation value for each point from the DEM, something like the [process described here](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/sampling-raster-values-at-point-locations-in-qgis/)
3. Open the attribute table in excel and make a line graph using the elevation values you acquired in step 2.

I've done this a few times when I wanted to show the profile of a linear project area and it works pretty well.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use the data and make it graphical, you can use the following QGIS plugin: [Trail Elevation Stats](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/trail_elevation_stats/).